# Looping through list of entities in a ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

One of my entities `Create` page needs to have a list of other entities, in this case the `Timetable` create view needs a list of `Station` entities. To achieve this I created my own ViewModel:

```
public class TimetablesCreateViewModel
{
    public Timetable Timetable { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Station> Stations { get; set; }
}
```

I then changed my `Create` methods in the `TimetablesController` class to be this:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    TimetablesCreateViewModel model = new TimetablesCreateViewModel
    {
        Timetable = new Timetable(),
        Stations = db.Stations.ToList()
    };

    return View();
}
```

I then modified my `Create.cshtml` page to use `@model MyApp.ViewModels.TimetablesCreateViewModel`, and I'm attempting to loop through `Station`s like this:

```
@foreach (var s in Model.Stations)
{
    <p>@s.Name</p>
}
```

When I load the `/Timetables/Create` page, I get a `NullReferenceException`:

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in
>   App_Web_lqnuresu.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.

The only thing I thought would be causing this is if no stations were populated into `Model.Stations`, but that's not the case, it's successfully retrieving all the stations in the database.

Comment: You're not passing the model to your view. Use `return View(model);`.

Comment: `return View(model);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the model with the view:

`return View(model);`